# Get dynamic column value

Tags: mysql, subquery, concatenation

I have a table student that contains :

```
  student_id , prefered_cell , cell_1 , cell_2 , cell_3
```

now under prefered cell values we have (cell_1,cell2,cell3)

what is the best way to get the value of the prefered cell in mysql ?

those are the available rows :

```
1 , 'cell_1' ,  '123-321-1231' , '431-2133-321' , '123-123-4111'
2 , 'cell_2' ,  '122-333-3333' , '455-123-123' , '123-421-2345'
```

so i want to have the preferred number for student 1 and 2 :

will get :

```
1 , '123-321-1231'
2 , '455-123-123'
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: your question it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query.

```
Select student_id, case when prefered_cell = 'cell_1' then cell_1 
                        when prefered_cell = 'cell_2' then cell_2
                        when prefered_cell = 'cell_3' then cell_3
                        else '0'
                        End  as cell_value from student
```

Answer (score 1):

we have switch in sql.You can use that

```
select student_id ,case  from table_name

 CASE prefered_cell 
    WHEN 'cell_1' THEN 'value is cell_1 '
    WHEN 'cell_2' THEN 'value is cell_2'
    WHEN 'cell_3'= 'cell_3' then cell_3
  END
  else '0'
   End from student
```